# smart choice in imacros for firefox

Tags: imacros

I play BiteFight game online , I use imacros to help me playing in adventure mode , it really helping me but the problem is (it had no brain to choose the right button every time)

I have to select one choice every step in the game , and the choices are changing every time

I want imacros to select the exact right selection every time , I tried to write the code line like this :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:attack
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:kill
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:hide
```

but the problem comes out , it did`t select the first choice which is the right one this time , and it keeps selecting a random choice every time

please help me with the right codes

Comment: You have to give us the HTML Code of tha BF page. Use pastebin.com

Comment: you can go here , it`s a test user
http://s4.us.bitefight.gameforge.com/user/login
user name:imacros.test
pass:imacros123
click:Raid , and you will go to adventure mode (i started it for you) and see what I am talking about